# PyTorch is installed. But, When I'm using BertModel, It is giving me following Import error:

Tags: python, error-handling, pytorch, importerror, bert-language-model

I installed and imported `PyTorch`. Still, I am getting this import error, while I'm using `BertModel`. I need some help here.

Error I'm getting is this:

> ImportError:  BertModel requires the PyTorch library but it was not found in your environment. However, we were able to find a TensorFlow installation. TensorFlow classes begin with "TF", but are otherwise identica

I tried this:

```py
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("Rostlab/prot_bert")
```

I'm getting this:

[image: Import Error is shown in the image]

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions given in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error but it has disappeared after restarting jupyter.